# Float value must be included for both minimum and maximum value

Tags: javascript, html

I have a minimum and maximum value textboxes. It is accepting only integer values but not float values. How to solve so that i can give both integer as well as float values?

Comment: Are you using standard text input boxes or `<input type=number/>`?

Comment: Show us your text box HTML code

Comment: no , i am not using <input type=number/> @ImanK

Comment: @srivatsas do you have your HTML or not?

Comment: i got the code , Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set attribute step a float value. then add min, max

```
<input type="number" step="0.01" min="0.02" max="5.05">
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```html
<input type="number" step="any" />
```

Comment: But i am unable to give decimal value

Comment: sorry , i did not get what you are saying.

Comment: what you want clear first and which code you tried for this share it ??? @srivatsas

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `step` attribute (the default definition is 1)

```html
<input type="number" step="0.01">
```